# react-router-dom history.goBack() not working on Firefox and Safari

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a component like this (simplified version)

```
import React, {Fragment, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Link, useHistory, useParams} from 'react-router-dom';

const MyComponent = () => {
  let history = useHistory();

  const handleGoBack = () => {
    console.log('going back...');
    history.go(-1); // or history.goBack();
  };

  return (
    <Fragment> 
      <Link to="#" onClick={handleGoBack}>&lt; Back</Link>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

it works as expected in chrome. not working at all in Firefox and safari. The console shows me the handleGoBack function is called as expected but the history.goBack does only on chrome.
any idea please?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the code you provided, but in something else. I created [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-pasteur-zu1ql) based on your code snippet, and `history.go(-1)` is working in latest versions of Firefox and Safari

Comment: Yes, history.go(-1) does work for me, thanks. In case someone is looking for a solution on older browsers, a longer workaround is posted here [link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/615) by zsajjad

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the exact same issue. So in your code, you are putting a link like this:

```
<Link to="#" onClick={handleGoBack}>&lt; Back</Link>
```

I saw that in firefox, that gets rendered as an anchor tag which has the url as current url.
So I just replaced that `Link` with a button and handled the onclick event as usual and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Fixed the issue for me on iOS 15, Safari!

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me while using React Router:
history.goBack() works, but I had to check for "/" and stop when that was reached.  The history counting business doesn't work, so I  had to search for the "/" path to know when to hide/disable the "<" back button.

```
import React  from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
import { NavBar, Icon } from "antd-mobile";
import MainSearchContainer from "../components/MainSearchContainer";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

function PageHeader({location, history, db}) {
   const appTitle = "My App";

   return (
      <React.Fragment>
         <NavBar
            icon={location.pathname !== "/" ? <Icon type="left" /> : ""}
            onLeftClick={() => { history.goBack(); render(); } }
            mode="dark"
            rightContent={[<Icon key="1" type="ellipsis" />]}
         >
            {appTitle}
         </NavBar>
         <MainSearchContainer db={db} history={history} />
      </React.Fragment>
   );
}

export default withRouter(PageHeader);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same issue, but Safari only. In my case the issue was caused by "#" present in href attribute in my "Go back" link. My onClick callback was not calling evt.preventDefault(), so it seems that the "#" was "overwriting" the history.goBack() call.

**Before**

```
onBackClick() 
{
    let history = this.props.history;
    history.goBack();
}

...

<a href="#" onClick={::this.onBackClick}><i className="fas fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

**After (Solution)**

```
onBackClick(evt) 
{
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();

    let history = this.props.history;
    history.goBack();
}

...

<a href="#" onClick={(evt)=>::this.onBackClick(evt)}><i className="fas fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```